# ng-app or angular.bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I was thinking when it would be best to not use the ng-App directive and instead go for angular.bootstrap. I understand from documentation what ng-App directive does and how it helps in telling compiler to set root of compilation. So my question is as to why I should use angular.bootstrap? What do they mean by saying in documentation that "If you need to have more control over the initialization process, you can use a manual bootstrapping method instead" [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap%20here). Then I would also like to know as to for the solution that I am thinking for my application. I have one `index.html` file with one ng-app directive. Now for my application, I have different APIs, lets say for admin, students and instructors. So this is what I was thinking.Have the following files:

```
index.html
admin.js
students.js
instructors.js
```

I will have controllers for all of them and separate moduels, which will get the data from those APIs. Each div that will display the data from those controllers will be associated with the specific module, using angular.bootstrap and index.html will not have the ng-App directive. Is this the right approach ?  Should I be just using ng-App and multiple controllers and a single module? Any help in understanding this is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: while the intent of your question is pretty clear, the details are all over the place.  you ask about bootstrapping the angular app but then describe a scenario that isn't addressed with bootstrapping, it's addressed by routing, unless you plan on having 3 different angular applicatons on the same page at the same time?  That is almost never a good idea, and even if it were, you would have to deal with the fact that the different apps can't communicate with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If you need to have more control over the initialization process, you can use a manual bootstrapping method instead"

This means that with ng-app whenever directive is encountered bootstrapping will start automatically.

But with manual bootstrapping we can control it, say we want some data to be loaded first, to check for something defined or not or even as normally we do with checking of DOM ready event.

Comment: So in my scenario, there wouldn't be a need for manual bootstrapping then? I was just trying to separate code in different files so that they can be easily maintained. But I guess that is a wrong approach for that??

Comment: Don't think so manual bootstrapping is the approach here. If you separate bootstrapping for each then it looks like you are creating separate apps used on same page. Separating the code is a different aspect, it should not be mingled with bootstrapping.

Answer (score 2):

One guideline that might help you is that you can only use `ng-app` once, but you can use `angular.bootstrap` multiple times

Comment: But how will it help me if I used angular.bootstrap on each of the divs which display my information. I guess I am trying to think about from the DOM point of view, as to how setting <html> as root of compilation will be treated differently from multiple angular.bootstrap. Doesn't compiler compile all of the page on one load anyhow? Is some div loading prioritized over other by angular.bootstrap?